# What can I do to recover a UTF-8 binary file?

Tags: mongodb, encoding, utf-8, binary

I somehow had a script running on my company's server that basically did a mongodump and then for some reason used recode to encode *all* .bson files to UTF-8. Thanks to that, I can't use mongorestore, as it says every single .bson file has 268 Mb.
Is there anything one can do to get data back from a **recoded** to UTF-8 **binary** BSON file? There's apparently no way to recode it back. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you discard this broken dump and get a fresh new one?

Comment: Depends on the settings you used for transcoding the file. If the process was set to omit all invalid utf-8 codepoints, then your files are irreparably damaged (because of the information loss). Best you can do is get a new dump.

Comment: Well, it ends up that we lost the local version of our database and never had to restore in the last month, so there's no other dump other than the damaged ones. I guess I'll have to rebuild the database or find any other cloud-stored version.
I hope this never happens to anyone else. Oh jeez

Answer (score 0):

OK. This works only on MongoDB, probably, but I'll put it as an answer because it may work for people with this exact problem:
BSON files, while binary, are somewhat readable, depending on your need. In my case, I had a product collection, and most of what I had to update was descriptions and such.
While not a perfect solution, it is possible to just use Notepad++ to turn hex characters into new lines or anything else, and try to parse the resulting file, if you know what you are doing.
Since all fields (name, _id, description) are still there, I recommend turning those into XML headers, for example.
That solved my problem. Thanks.